# Trouble running PHPUnit in Travis Build

Tags: php, phpunit, composer-php, travis-ci

I am having some trouble running PHPUnit from Travis.

My travis configuration is simple

```
language: php
php:
  - 7.0
  - 7.1
script: phpunit
```

And my phpunit.xml is as follows,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<phpunit bootstrap="vendor/autoload.php">
    <testsuites>
        <testsuite name="Basic Test Suite">
            <directory suffix=".php">./tests/</directory>
        </testsuite>
    </testsuites>
</phpunit>
```

And my composer.json

```
{
    "name": "nikhilkuria/nikeandphp",
    "description": "A PHP library used to work with Nike+ API",
    "type": "library",
    "authors": [
        {
            "name": "nikhilkuria",
            "email": "nikhilkuria@gmail.com"
        }
    ],
    "require": {
        "monolog/monolog": "^1.22"
    },
    "require-dev": {
      "phpunit/phpunit": "5.7.*"
    },
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {"NikeAndPhp\\": "src/NikeAndPhp"}
}
}
```

The problem is that Travis is not able to find my autoload.php. This is what i see in travis logs,

Cannot open file "/home/travis/build/nikhilkuria/nikeandphp/vendor/autoload.php".

The entire logs are [here](https://travis-ci.org/nikhilkuria/nikeandphp/jobs/205474909).

What seems to be missing here?

Comment: The link to the entire logs doesn't work

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As I can see from your log output you're not running `composer install` command, that's why you're getting `Cannot open file "/home/travis/build/nikhilkuria/nikeandphp/vendor/autoload.php".` error message.

Add

```
before_script:
    - composer install
```

Comment: While it doesn't make any difference it would be semantically more correct to install dependencies in the `install` section, see https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/customizing-the-build#The-Build-Lifecycle.

Answer (score 6):

Aside from the fact that your Travis configuration is missing the `composer install` step there is also something wrong with the way you install PHPUnit.

`script: phpunit` means that you invoke PHPUnit using the globally installed PHPUnit that is available as `phpunit` on the `$PATH`. You most likely do not want that as you have listed PHPUnit as a development dependency in your `composer.json`. To use the PHPUnit installed using Composer you need to use `script: ./vendor/bin/phpunit` instead.

Comment: This did the trick. Adding script: ./vendor/bin/phpunit tests/ - Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

## Individual bin-path

for the case that in composer.json an individual bin-path is defined, the path to phpunit has to be adjusted accordingly.

**composer.json:**

```
{
  ...
  "config": {
    "vendor-dir": ".Build/vendor",
    "bin-dir": ".Build/bin",
  },
  ...
}
```

**.travis.yaml:**

```
language: php  
...
script:
  - >
    echo;
    echo "Running unit tests";
    .Build/bin/phpunit --colors  -c .Build/vendor/.../UnitTests.xml
...
```